Pass variables with vue 3 router
I have a newsCard component in vue 3 using options API. When the user clicks on this card I want them to go to a page displaying the full news article. However, I need to pass some data to this full news article like title, mediaURL and text content. I tried to pass it as a state:
  clickedCard() {
    const countryCode = this.$route.params.countryCode || 'sv';
    const id = this.blockData.id.slice(0, 10);
    const publishDate = this.blockData.publishDate.split('T')[0].replace(/-/g, '');

    this.$router.push({
      path: `/${countryCode}/${this.newsSectionSlug}/${id}-${publishDate}`,
      state: {
        title: this.blockData.title,
        mediaURL: this.blockData.mediaURL,
        mediaType: this.blockData.mediaType,
        defaultImage: this.defaultImage,
        content: this.blockData.content,
        publishDate: this.blockData.publishDate
      }
    });
  }

With the following in my router index.js file:
  {
    path: '/:countryCode/:newsSectionSlug/:id-:publishDate',
    name: 'NewsPage',
    component: NewsPage,
    props: true
  }

Now when I try to access these in the NewsPage.vue view/component I can't. I console log in NewsPage.vue:
mounted() {
    console.log(this.$router.currentRoute.value)
  }

Which gives me this (no state variable):
{fullPath: '/sv/nyheter/96427258-4-20240926', path: '/sv/nyheter/96427258-4-20240926', query: {…}, hash: '', name: 'NewsPage', …}
fullPath
: 
"/sv/nyheter/96427258-4-20240926"
hash
: 
""
href
: 
"/sv/nyheter/96427258-4-20240926"
matched
: 
[{…}]
meta
: 
{}
name
: 
"NewsPage"
params
: 
countryCode
: 
"sv"
id
: 
"96427258"
newsSectionSlug
: 
"nyheter"
publishDate
: 
"4-20240926"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
path
: 
"/sv/nyheter/96427258-4-20240926"
query
: 
{}
redirectedFrom
: 
undefined
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Requirements:

The route needs to go to e.g. mydomain.com/sv/nyheter/title-id-or-other-of-news-item
The page component/view needs to get title, mediaURL, mediaType, content and publishDate (content can be large).
Page must be able to reload

Chatgpt suggests localStorage or Pinia which seems like an unnecessary solution since I just want to pass parameters to the new page.
1. Is this the right approach for this?
2. If so, how can I make it work to access the state variables?

Don't use state, it's half-baked https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/400 . This is the case for global store. "Page must be able to reload" - do you mean that "state" you provided should be available at that route on page reload? Then persist data. You can't reserve anything that isn't in url otherwise

The 'state' paramers should like this?
this.$router.push({path:`/${countryCode}/${this.newsSectionSlug}/${id}-${publishDate}`,query:{state:{...}}})

console.log(this.$route.query.state)

or contact the state to the path, get the params.

The best way to go here is by getting the data in the news article component itself, based on the article ID you pass in the route params.
Keep your routes simple and get the data where you need it (from a store, a fetch request, ...).
